# Creating indexes with T-SQL returns index exists error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

What I'm trying to do is make a copy of a table using a SELECT INTO statement.

After the table is created I want to duplicate the indexes as well.

So the code I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT * INTO TableCopy FROM Table
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE TableCopy ADD CONSTRAINT pkGUID PRIMARY KEY ([GUID])
CREATE INDEX ixIndexName ON TableCopy (CountryCode)
```

When I execute the index SQL, I get an error that the indexes already exist in the catalog.  I didn't think index names had to be unique, I thought they could be duplicated across different tables.

And lo and behold if I create the indexes through management studio, it accepts the index names.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I didn't think index names had to be unique, I thought they could be duplicated across different tables.

No. They do have to be unique within a table/view.

When you execute within SSMS, it **drops** the existing index and creates a new one.

From [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on MSDN:

> index_name - Is the name of the index. **Index names must be unique within a table or view** but do not have to be unique within a database.

(emphasis mine)

---

However, `pkGUID` is not an index - it is a **constraint**, and these do have to be unique within a database.

Comment: Index names don't have to be unique. **Constraint** names do.

Comment: I have two tables in my database with pkGUID as a primary key and when I check the properties, I don't see that SSMS has assigned a different name to either of them

Comment: @Tom - `pkGUID` is the name of a _constraint_ not an index.

Comment: @Oded So is the syntax to create a clustered primary key different than what I have above?

Comment: @Tom - You are confusing constraints with indexes. A constraint name has to be unique within a database. And index name doesn't. You need to give the primary key constraint a _different_ name to the existing one. I assume SSMS does that.

Comment: @Oded - yeah, I'm definitely confused.  As you can see from this screenshot within SSMS, I have two separate tables with the same primary key name. If I go further and open the property pages, I see nothing unique that SSMS has assigned to the name.  But if I use the code above to create a primary key, I get the dup error...http://i.imgur.com/2fU1q.jpg

Comment: @Tom - I see two identical **index** names. Open up the `Keys` nodes.

Comment: @Oded - ah ok, I get it now.  I don't NEED to name the constraint but if I do, the name needs to be unique.  Thanks for clarifying all this.